# Assign random to several values at a time

Tags: python, random, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get used to list comprehensions, but I struggle with this-
How can I assign random integers to several values at a time?

My solution is this:

```
a,b,c=random.sample(100, 3)
```

But when I run code it gives me error:

```
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

I think there shoud be solution to avoid simply repeating this three times like:

```
a=random.randint(0,99)
b=random.randint(0,99)
c=random.randint(0,99)
```

Comment: The issue comes from your `random.sample(100, 3)`. Samples must be taken from a sequence of values, 100 is an integer not a sequence

Comment: Have a list of integers and loop through, possibly. I don't think it is possible to do it condensed down without some sort of list. Possibly make it a function which returns all the variables?

Comment: `random.sample(range(100), 3)`? Also, note that the two given snippets have different behaviour, in the first `a`, `b`, and `c` all must be different, while in the second, they can be the same.

Comment: @internet_user in Python 3.6, you can use `random.choices` for sampling with replacement... before that, you'd have to do something like `[random.choice(list_of_vals) for _ in range(n)]` instead of `random.choices(list_of_vals, k=n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The population of `random.sample` i.e. the first argument needs to be a sequence or a set, but you have given an integer.

Based on what you want to get, `range(101)` as the population should do:

```
In [41]: a, b, c = random.sample(range(101), 3)

In [42]: a 
Out[42]: 16

In [43]: b
Out[43]: 61

In [44]: c
Out[44]: 13
```